# Long text overlay over two cells in xls-fo

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

how to do long text overlay over two cells (like in excel when text is to long for one, then it's expanded on next cell)

```
<fo:table-cell white-space="nowrap">
    <fo:block margin-left="1cm" >blablabla<xsl:value-of select="sth"/> sthsthsthsth</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block/>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omit the following cell and use number-columns-spanned="2" but this behavior is not going to automatically happen if the text happens to be long. It is always going to span two columns regardless of length.